# Confusion in the order of the differentials in integral using differential forms

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

My doubt is very general but I'm going to give an example so I can explain why I'm struggling with this.

I have a 2-form $\alpha$ written in Cartesian coordinates

$$
\alpha=\alpha_{ij}\,dx^i\wedge dx^j
$$

If I want to integrate this on a 2-sphere $S^2\in\mathbb R^3$, I'm going to change $\alpha$ to spherical coordinates $(x,y,z)\to(r,\theta,\phi)$ and have something like this

$$
\int_{S^2}\alpha= \int \alpha'_{\theta\phi} \,d\theta \wedge d\phi
$$

But I know that $d\theta \wedge d\phi=-d\phi \wedge d\theta $, so I also have

$$
\int_{S^2}\alpha= -\int \alpha'_{\theta\phi} \,d\phi \wedge d\theta
$$

Which is the correct way to integrate $\alpha$ over $S^2$?

$$
\int_{S^2}\alpha= \int \alpha'_{\theta\phi} \,d\theta \,d\phi
\quad\text{or}\quad
\int_{S^2}\alpha= -\int \alpha'_{\theta\phi} \,d\theta \,d\phi
$$

I can't discern difference between the two integrals, I need a procedure to choose the correct way to integrate. And the thing is worse when I'm trying to integrate things less intuitive and with other manifolds.

I don't find any source either with clear examples and where I can understand

Comment: Strictly speaking, you cannot integrate $2$-forms on $S^2$ unless you first specify an orientation of $S^2$. This orientation will determine the appropriate choice of sign.

Comment: @Kajelad So I suppose I have a lack of knowledge in certain concepts. If I accomplish to understand the concept of orientation and its relation with $p$-forms, I will be able to integrate without ambiguity, is that correct?

Comment: The answer below is very good. But let me note that you make a mistake in conflating $d\phi\wedge d\theta$ (as you write in your penultimate set of equations) with $d\phi d\theta$ (with no wedge, as you write in your final set of equations). These are not the same object. The former is a differential form; the latter is a density. You need the orientation to turn the differential form into a density in a consistent way. But regardless, the integrals of the reversed *differential forms* really *do* have opposite signs. There is no contradiction, that is, in the first two integrals you write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is an oriented $m$-dimensional manifold and $\alpha$ is a smooth compactly-supported $m$-form on $M$. Then, we can consider its integral $\int_M\alpha$. Note that this integral depends on the choice of orientation for $M$. For simple examples like balls, ellipsoids, (one half of) hyperboloids, paraboloids or their boundary surfaces, we can usually use a single chart $(U,\psi)$ to cover the entire manifold, up to a "negligible set". If the chart is orientation-preserving, then we can write
\begin{align}
\int_M\alpha&=\int_U\alpha=\int_{\psi^{-1}[\psi(U)]}\alpha=\int_{\psi(U)}(\psi^{-1})^*\alpha\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
where on the RHS, $(\psi^{-1})^*\alpha$ is an $m$-form on an open subset $\psi(U)$ of $\Bbb{R}^m$, and thus can be written as $(\psi^{-1})^*\alpha=f\,dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^m$, where $(x^1,\dots, x^m)$ is the usual cartesian coordinate chart on $\Bbb{R}^m$ (and thus $dx^1\wedge \cdots\wedge dx^m$ is indeed the volume form), and for a unique function $f:\psi(U)\to\Bbb{R}$. So, we have
\begin{align}
\int_M\alpha&=\int_{\psi(U)}f\,dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^k:=\int_{\psi(U)}f,
\end{align}
where the last symbol is a Riemann/Lebesgue integral of a function $f:\psi(U)\to\Bbb{R}$, i.e a standard integral. So far, all I've done is chase definitions.

As a remark, if $\psi$ is an orientation-reversing chart, then we must modify $(*)$ to
\begin{align}
\int_M\alpha&=\int_U\alpha=\int_{\psi^{-1}[\psi(U)]}\alpha=-\int_{\psi(U)}(\psi^{-1})^*\alpha.
\end{align}

---

Now, let us recall how we can induce orientations. Suppose $(M,g)$ is an $m$-dimensional oriented Riemannian manifold with Riemannian volume form $\mu$. Let $S$ is an $(m-1)$ dimensional embedded submanifold (i.e a smooth hypersurface) which admits a smooth unit normal vector field $n$ (i.e $n:S\to TM$ is a smooth map such that for each $p\in S$, we have $g_p(n_p,n_p)=1$ and for each $\xi\in T_pS$, $g_p(n_p, \xi)=0$). Then, we have the induced volume form $\mu_S:= \iota_S^*(n \lrcorner \mu)$, i.e the pullback to $S$ of the interior product of $n$ with $\mu$. This means, for each $p\in S$ and $\xi_1,\dots, \xi_{m-1}\in T_pS$, we have
\begin{align}
(\mu_S)_p(\xi_1,\dots, \xi_{m-1})&:=\mu_p(n_p,\xi_1,\dots, \xi_{m-1}).
\end{align}
In particular, what this means is $\{\xi_1,\dots, \xi_{m-1}\}$ is a positively-oriented ordered basis of $T_pS$ (i.e the LHS above is $>0$) if and only if $\{n_p,\xi_1,\dots, \xi_{m-1}\}$ is a positively-oriented ordered basis of $T_pM$ (i.e the RHS above is $>0$). (Also, $\mu_S$ is indeed the Riemannian volume form of $S$, relative to the pullback metric $\iota_S^*g$, because if we chose the $\xi$'s to be positively oriented and orthonormal, then the RHS is equal to $1$ by definition of $\mu$ being the Riemannian volume form of $M$).

For more details about orientation, you should consult any differential geometry book, for example Spivak or Lee (Chapter 15 of Intro to Smooth Manifolds)

---

Now, we come to the case of the sphere $S^2$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$. Note that $\Bbb{R}^3$ has the standard Riemannian metric
\begin{align}
g=dx\otimes dx+dy\otimes dy+dz\otimes dz
\end{align}
and volume form
\begin{align}
\mu&=dx\wedge dy\wedge dz
\end{align}
Now, introduce spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$ on a certain open subset of $\Bbb{R}^3$. Then, a standard calculation shows (equality obviously only on an appropriate open set of $\Bbb{R}^3$)
\begin{align}
\mu&=r^2\sin\theta\,dr\wedge d\theta\wedge d\phi.
\end{align}
The sphere obviously admits a unit normal vector field, and by convention, we choose $n=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ (restricted to $S^2$) to be the "outward pointing" unit normal. By my remarks above, this induces an orientation on $S^2$ with the volume form (I suppress the pullback to a certain open subset of $S^2$ in the notation)
\begin{align}
\mu_{S^2}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \lrcorner \,r^2\sin\theta\,dr\wedge d\theta\wedge d\phi\\
&=\sin\theta\,d\theta\wedge d\phi
\end{align}
(the $r^2$ becomes $1$ since when we pullback to $S^2$, the radius is $1$). The range of $(\theta(\cdot),\phi(\cdot))$ is the open set $A:=(0,\pi)\times(0,2\pi)\subset\Bbb{R}^2$, which means $\sin\theta>0$, and thus the differential form $d\theta\wedge d\phi$ defines the same orientation as $\mu_{S^2}=\sin\theta\,d\theta\wedge d\phi$. **Therefore, the spherical coordinate mapping which identifies an open subset of $S^2$ with $A$ preserves orientation.**

In short, once you pull everything back to $A$, you deal with $d\theta\wedge d\phi$ (I'm abusing notation slightly here, since throughout I've used $\theta,\phi$ to mean functions on an open subset of $S^2$, so logically speaking I should refer to the corresponding coordinate functions on $A$ as $\tilde{\theta}$ and $\tilde{\phi}$), and as I mentioned in my formula $(*)$ in the beginning, due to the orientation-preserving nature, we don't introduce any rogue minus signs.

---

**Edit In Response to Comment.**

I didn't want to have to do this initially because it would require us to introduce extra notation. One should always be careful of where each object lives. Recall that in general, when we say $(U,\psi)$ is a chart for an $m$-dimensional manifold $M$, it means $U\subset M$ is open and $\psi:U\to \psi[U]\subset \Bbb{R}^m$ is a mapping from the manifold to the cartesian space. Since $\psi$ maps into $\Bbb{R}^m$, we can consider its component functions $\psi(\cdot)=(x^1_{\psi}(\cdot),\dots, x^m_{\psi}(\cdot))$, so $x^i_{\psi}(\cdot)$ is the $i^{th}$ coordinate function of $\psi$ (it's what one might typically write as $\psi^i(\cdot)$, but let us stick to $x^i_{\psi}(\cdot)$).

Next, if $A\subset \Bbb{R}^m$ is an open set, when we speak of "cartesian coordinates on $A$" what we mean is the identity chart $\text{id}_A:A\to A\subset\Bbb{R}^m$. In keeping with the above notation, $\text{id}_A(\cdot)= (x^1_{\text{id}_A}(\cdot),\dots, x^m_{\text{id}_A}(\cdot))$.

Now, when we speak of spherical coordinates on $S^2$, we're talking about a specific chart $(U,\psi)$. It is rather cumbersome to give the definition of $\psi$ (because inverting the trig functions is a little annoying). So, it is convenient to first define $A=(0,\pi)\times (0,2\pi)$ and consider the mapping $A\subset\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^3$,
\begin{align}
(\theta,\phi)\mapsto (\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)
\end{align}
The image of this mapping is an open set $U\subset S^2$, and the inverse of this mapping is called $\psi$. This is the definition of the chart $(U,\psi)$. What I've claimed above is that
\begin{align}
\mu_{S^2}&=\sin(x_{\psi}^1(\cdot))\,dx_{\psi}^1\wedge dx_{\psi}^2
\end{align}
Notice that $\sin(x_{\psi}^1(\cdot))$ is a function $U\to\Bbb{R}$, and $dx_{\psi}^1$ is the exterior derivative of a function on $U$, and thus is a $1$-form on $U$ and so on. Thus, the RHS is properly a $1$-form on $U$.

To check that $\psi:U\to A$ is indeed an orientation preserving chart it means I have to take the volume form  on $\mu_A$ and then show that $\psi^*(\mu_A)=(\text{strictly positive function})\mu_{S^2}$.

Now, $\mu_A=dx_{\text{id}_A}^1\wedge dx_{\text{id}_A}^2$ by definition. Let us now calculate the pullback of $\mu_A$ under $\psi$. For this, we need to recall that pullback commutes with wedge products and exterior derivatives:
\begin{align}
\psi^*(\mu_A)&=\psi^*(dx_{\text{id}_A}^1\wedge dx_{\text{id}_A}^2)\\
&=d(\psi^*x^1_{\text{id}_A})\wedge d(\psi^*x^2_{\text{id}_A})\\
&=d(x^1_{\text{id}_A}\circ \psi)\wedge d(x^2_{\text{id}_A}\circ \psi)\\
&=d(x^1_{\psi})\wedge d(x^2_{\psi})\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin(x^1_{\psi}(\cdot))}\,\mu_{S^2}
\end{align}
Since the sin is strictly positive here, we have indeed shown that $\psi^*(\mu_A)$ is a positive multiple of $\mu_{S^2}$, and thus $(U,\psi)$ is an orientation-preserving chart.

Prior to this edit, I called $x^1_{\psi},x_{\psi}^2$ as $\theta,\phi$ respectively, and $x^1_{\text{id}_A},x^2_{\text{id}_A}$ as $\tilde{\theta},\tilde{\phi}$. So, $\theta=\tilde{\theta}\circ \psi$ and likewise for $\phi$ (this is what I mean by non-tilde are functions on $U$ and tilde are the associated functions on $A$). So,
\begin{align}
\psi^*(\mu_A)&=\psi^*(d\tilde{\theta}\wedge d\tilde{\phi})\\
&=d(\tilde{\theta}\circ \psi)\wedge d(\tilde{\phi}\circ\psi)\\
&=d\theta\wedge d\phi\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\mu_{S^2}
\end{align}
and this differs by a positive multiple from $\mu_{S^2}$, hence $\psi$ is orientation preserving.

Note that because the pullback operation is so natural and plays nicely with wedge products and exterior derivatives, we usually don't like to introduce excessive notation to distinguish between functions on $U$ vs functions on $A$ obtained by composing with the chart map $\psi$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail oriented answer, I think you gave me more than enough. I've got a question, maybe I'm oversimplifying things and missing important subtleties, but if I have the induced volume $\mu_S=h \,du^1\wedge\cdots\wedge du^{m-1}$ over $S$ with $h>0$, then the following is true $\int_S\mu_S=\int_A h\,du^1\cdots du^{m-1}$ where $A$ is the range of $(u^1,\ldots,u^{m-1})$. Am I right?

Comment: @BorisValderrama almost: $h$ and $u^i$ are technically a function on $S$ so you should convert them into a functions $\tilde{h}$, $\tilde{u}^i$ on $A$. Then, $\int_S\mu_S=\int_Sh\,du^1\wedge \cdots \wedge du^{m-1}=\int_A\tilde{h}\,d\tilde{u}^1\cdots d\tilde{u}^{m-1}$, where the RHS is now a standard Riemann/Lebesgue integral. Of course, usually one doesn't bother introducing new letters for them because they usually know where everything lives.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I noticed you said that $(U,\psi)$ is orientation-preserving, in this case this is not applicable, right? because $\psi:A\subset \mathbb R^2\to S^2\subset \mathbb R^3$ and the determinant of the Jacobian of $\psi$ is not defined.

Comment: Here, $\psi:U\subset S^2\subset \Bbb{R}^3\to A\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ (recall the charts go from the manifold to the cartesian space... but in this case of spherical coordinates, it is easier to actually define the inverse map $\psi^{-1}:A\to U$). For each point $p\in U$, we can consider the tangent mapping $T\psi_p:T_pU=T_pS^2\to T_pA\cong \Bbb{R}^2$. The linear map $T\psi_p$ is between 2-dimensional oriented real vector spaces, so it certainly makes sense to speak of orientation-preserving.

Comment: An equivalent way of phrasing the orientation-preserving nature is using differential forms. Namely, suppose $f:M\to N$ is a diffeomorphism between oriented manifolds, say having volume forms $\mu_M$ and $\mu_N$. We can define $f$ to be orientation preserving if $f^*(\mu_N)=h\cdot \mu_M$ for some smooth function $h:M\to (0,\infty)$ (notice we require it to be strictly positive).

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd expand on my comment about the difference between $d\phi\wedge d\theta$ and $d\phi d\theta$, since I consider this point a rather pervasive source of confusion. All of what I say is consistent with peek-a-boo's excellent answer, but I want to place the emphasis elsewhere: on the difference between integrating differential forms like $d\phi\wedge d\theta$ and integrating densities like $d\phi d\theta$ (the differential geometric analogues of measures).

The central difference between the two kinds of integrals is how they transform under a change of variables. Differential forms transform via a factor of the Jacobian, whereas densities (and measures) transform via a factor of the *absolute value of* the Jacobian. It's the fact that the differential forms version of the change of variables theorem lacks the absolute value sign that causes all the trouble with sign book-keeping and orientations.

Densities / measures are the objects we are more familiar with from ordinary integration theory, before we start doing vector calculus and Stokes's theorem. When we integrate a function over a set in the plane, say (whether Riemann or Lebesgue), we do not require the set to have an orientation. It turns out this notion extends naturally to the setting of manifolds with a Riemannian metric. That is, on any *Riemannian* manifold, whether orientable or not, it is possible to integrate scalar functions with respect to volume over measurable subsets of the manifold. The Möbius strip, for example, is a two-dimensional *non*-orientable manifold, but it still makes sense to speak of its area (the integral of the constant function $1$ with respect to the strip's area element). The reason is that we can use the Riemannian metric to define a Riemannian *density* in a canonical way: that is the "area" (or more generally "volume") "element" we integrate functions with respect to. Roughly speaking, the metric tells us how to compute the volume of infinitesimal parallelepipeds; more precisely, the density at a particular point $p$ of an $n$-manifold $M$ is a nonlinear function of $n$ tangent vectors in the tangent space $T_pM$ that behaves like the absolute value of the determinant on the tangent space. It's because we take the absolute value that the integral of a density remains intrinsically defined, even under an orientation-reversing change of local coordinates. (The word "density" is helpfully suggestive, by the way. Suppose you build a Möbius strip with non-uniform mass density per unit area and you wish to find the total mass of the whole strip. To do so, you just integrate the mass density over the whole strip.)

Now, what about integrating differential forms? The trouble all stems from losing the absolute value sign. Consider two charts, $(U,\phi_U)$ and $(V,\phi_V)$, around a point $p$ in a manifold $M$ (not necessarily oriented). Note that the transition map $\phi_V\circ\phi_U^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism of $\phi_U(U\cap V)$ onto $\phi_V(U\cap V)$.

Say we want to integrate the form $\omega$ over $U\cap V$. The natural thing to try is to just pull everything back to Euclidean space:

$$\int_{U\cap V}\omega:=\int_{\phi_U(U\cap V)}(\phi_U^{-1})^*\omega$$

where the integral on the right is just ordinary integration of a differential form in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The first trouble is that this definition is explicitly coordinate dependent. So we try to check that it doesn't matter whether we use $\phi_V$ for the pullback on $U\cap V$ (or any other coordinate chart around $p$, for that matter). That is, we need to compare

$$\color{blue}{\int_{\phi_U(U\cap V)}(\phi_U^{-1})^*\omega}\,\,\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\,\,\color{red}{\int_{\phi_V(U\cap V)}(\phi_V^{-1})^*\omega}$$

**Proposition**. If $U\cap V$ is connected, then the red and blue integrals agree up to sign.

> *Proof*. Observe that
>
> $$\color{blue}{\int_{\phi_U(U\cap V)}(\phi_U^{-1})^*\omega}=\int_{\phi_U(U\cap V)}(\phi_V^{-1}\circ\phi_V\circ\phi_U^{-1})^*\omega=\color{green}{\int_{\phi_U(U\cap V)}(\phi_V\circ\phi_U^{-1})^*(\phi_V^{-1})^*\omega}$$
>
> where I've used $(f\circ g)^*\omega=g^*f^*\omega$.
>
> Now, if $U\cap V$ is connected, so is $\phi_U(U\cap V)$, since
> $\phi_U$ is continuous. Thus $\det D(\phi_V\circ\phi_U^{-1})$ has
> constant sign on $\phi_U(U\cap V)$.
>
> If the determinant is positive, the change of variables theorem for
> differential forms tells us that the green integral equals the red
> integral. On the other hand, if the determinant is negative, the
> change of variables theorem implies that the green integral is the
> opposite of the red integral. QED.

As a consequence of this argument, $\int_{U\cap V}\omega$ will be well-defined so long as we work only with charts whose transition maps have positive Jacobian. An *oriented* atlas on a manifold is precisely an atlas consisting of such charts.

I hope this concrete calculation clarifies why differential forms cannot be integrated on a manifold unless we pick an orientation (which is a maximal oriented atlas). Picking an orientation eliminates the obstruction to well-definedness under a change of coordinates.

Comment: this is a very good distinction to draw between densities and forms (though I don't think OP used $d\theta\,d\phi$ to mean a density). As a reference for any interested future reader: Loomis and Sternberg's [Advanced Calculus](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf) Sections 10.3 deals with densities and 10.4 deals with the Riemannian volume density (which also works for pseudo-Riemannian metrics). Also, in section 11.2, they introduce the integrals of forms by emphasizing that the orientation allows us to "think of" forms as densities and thus integrate them.

Comment: Thanks! A classic reference, too. I don’t think OP knows what a density is, but there’s a definite point of confusion in the question; as I mention in a comment above, there is no contradiction in the integrals containing the forms. The contradiction only arises in the pullback to the Euclidean density, where one doesn’t know what sign to pick. That’s why I wanted to iron this out a bit.