# What am I actually doing when I write a differential form in coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

For some reason I have never actually thought about this too hard, but now I am getting myself confused. Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, and $\omega\in \Omega^k(M)$. Let $(U,\phi)$ be a coordinate chart with coordinates $(x^1,\dots, x^n)$. Then, on $U$ we can "write $\omega$ in coordinates" as:
\begin{align*}
\omega|_U=\sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_k}\omega_{i_1\cdots i_k}dx^{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_k}
\end{align*}
where the $\omega_{i_1\cdots i_k}$ are smooth functions $U$.

In this sense, the wedge products $dx^{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_k}$'s form a local coordinate frame for the bundle $\Lambda^k(T^*M)$, however, in practice when I write a differential form in coordinates, it seems that I am actually writing forms on $\Lambda^k(T^*\phi(U))$, which I guess is the point, but I am getting myself confused a bit.

For example, suppose $M=S^2$ equipped with the round metric, then I can write the volume for $\omega_g$ in the angle coordinates as:
\begin{align*}
\omega_g|_U=\sin\theta d\theta\wedge d\phi
\end{align*}
but this to me seems like a differential form on $\phi(U)$, where $\phi$ is the chart defined implicitly by its inverse:
\begin{align*}
\phi^{-1}=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)
\end{align*}
so I really think we should be writing:
\begin{align*}
\phi^{-1*}\omega_g=\sin\theta d\theta\wedge d\phi
\end{align*}
and that:
\begin{align*}
\omega_g|_U=\phi^*(\sin\theta d\theta\wedge d\phi)
\end{align*}
In general, when writing a differential form in coordinates, I think we should really be writing:
\begin{align*}
\phi^{-1*}\omega=\sum_{i_1<\cdots <i_k}\omega_{i_1\cdots i_k}dx^{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_k}
\end{align*}
and:
\begin{align*}
\omega|_U=\phi^*\left(\sum_{i_1<\cdots <i_k}\omega_{i_1\cdots i_k}dx^{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_k}\right)
\end{align*}
where the $\omega_{i_1\cdots i_k}$ are smooth function on $\phi(U)$.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: No, this is perfectly fine. But in practice we don't write the $(\phi^{-1})^*$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok,  but then why do we refer to the $\omega_{i_1\cdots i_k}$ as smooth functions on $U$, when they are really smooth functions on $\phi(U)$?

Comment: Again, we just identify $U$ and $\phi(U)$ when we do local calculations. Do you really want to write $\omega_{i_1\dots i_k}(\phi^{-1}(x))$? When we say we're computing on (in) a coordinate chart, we are computing entirely in the open subset of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess not, it just feels very morally different from using an arbitrary local frame, and how we work in coordinates with vector fields

Comment: I don't know what you mean by an arbitrary local frame. But it's certainly the same way I have always worked with vector fields in coordinates!!!

Comment: It’s a matter of definitions. Is your $\theta$ a function on $U$ or on $\phi[U]$? People go back and forth and with a bit of practice, no one really cares anymore because they know what they’re doing. Also, while we’re here talking about notation, don’t you find it funny that you’re using $\phi$ for the chart map and also one of the angular coordinates :) If you want a whole commentary on notation, [here you go](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4223267/568204).

Comment: A pedantic remark, but since we’re talking notation/terminology, why not: “it seems that I am actually writing forms on $\Lambda^k(T^*\phi(U))$” umm no, you mean a $k$-form **on $\phi[U]$**. If I were to robotically interpret what you said I would interpret that you mean a differential form defined on the manifold $\Lambda^k(T^*\phi[U])$, which is the total space of a certain vector bundle.

Comment: If $f$ is a function, then $df$ is a $1$-form. A coordinate such as $\phi$ is a function on an open subset of the manifold, and $d\phi$ is its differential.

Comment: If you let $\theta, \phi$ denote the coordinate functions $U \to \mathbb R$ (so that they are functions defined on a subset of $M$ itself), then $\sin \theta \, d\theta\ \wedge d\phi$ is genuinely defined on $U$. I guess you're thinking of $\theta, \phi$ as being the standard coordinates $x^1, x^2$ on $\phi(U) \subset \mathbb R^2$ instead?

Comment: I second Anthony's comment. The functions $x^1,\dots,x^n$ are functions of type $U\to\mathbb R$ and their exterior derivatives are $1$-forms on $U$.